# Can I center a border with CSS?

Tags: css, border

I'm trying to center the dotted line horizontally with CSS. At the moment, it appears at the bottom. Is there a way I can offset it with -5px or something?

**HTML**

```
<div class="divider"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.divider {
    background: aqua url("styles/images/divider-stars.png") no-repeat center 0;
    height:30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    float: left;
    border-bottom: 2px dotted #b38b0d;
    }
```

Comment: Your problem is a bit unclear. If it's already 100% width, why do you need to center it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

no. But you can create another element that have the `border` and move it within the `.divider`

**html**

```
<div class="divider">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.inner {
 margin-top:19px;
 border-bottom: 2px dotted #b38b0d;   
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/5xMG7/

Answer (score 6):

You could also use `:before` or `:after` pseudo-selectors, to get rid of the inner element.

```html
<div class="divider"></div>
```

```css
.divider {
    background: aqua url("styles/images/divider-stars.png") no-repeat center 0;
    height: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    float: left;
}

.divider:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin-top: 19px;
    border-bottom: 2px dotted #b38b0d;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5xMG7/540/

Answer (score 1):

If you mean center it vertically, one way you can do it is like this:

```
<div class="divider"><span class="line"></span></div>

.divider {
    background: aqua url("styles/images/divider-stars.png") no-repeat center 0;
    height:30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    float: left;
    }
.line
{
   border-bottom: 2px dotted #b38b0d;
   margin-top:15px;
    display:block;
}
```