# Adding linking lines between two elements using css / jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have created a wizard like UI(below screenshot). But I am not sure how to add a line linking  point 1 to 2, highlighted withing the red box, when the user on the step 1 presses next and navigates to step 2. Is it possible using CSS / jQuery? I googled up but couldn't find anything on how to go about this. Any pointer on how to do this will also be helpful. Thanks!

```
 <table width="100%">

        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">
                <div class="circleBase numberDiv1">
                    <font class="ft1">1</font>
                </div><br/>
                <div  id="myNewLink1" >
                    <font class="ft">step 1</font>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">
                <div class="circleBase numberDiv2">
                    <font class="ft1">2</font>
                </div><br/>
                <div href="#" id="myNewLink2" >
                    <font class="ft">step 2</font>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">
                <div class="circleBase numberDiv3">
                    <font class="ft1">3</font>
                </div><br/>
                <div href="#" id="myNewLink3" >
                    <font class="ft">step 3</font>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">
                <div class="circleBase numberDiv4">
                    <font class="ft1">4</font>
                </div><br/>
                <div href="#" id="myNewLink4" >
                    <font class="ft">step 4</font>
                </div>
            </td>    
       </tr>
    </table>
```

[image: css]

Comment: So, you want the linking bar to highlight with red on a click?

Comment: Can you please show us the relevant CSS code?

Comment: You'll probably want to use SVG for this. Check out jsPlumb.

Comment: @user2067005 : no, actually I wanted the linking black lines between the steps. When the user in step 1 screen clicks on "go to step 2 button", the line should connect step1 and step 2.

Comment: Will the lines always be straight/horizontal lines? You could use a div in between them, set the height to the thickness of the line, and then give it a background color...

Comment: @sameermiraj so the lines only display when the next steps are clicked?

Comment: @crush: Yes, the lines will be horizontal.Will give the "div" method  a try..

Comment: @user2067005: Yes, it should appear when the user click on a button

Comment: @sameermiraj Do you actually have the lines? From what i see looking at you html, i don't see the lines. Also the css would be nice

Comment: @user2067005 I think his question was how to do the lines...

Comment: the easy way would be to make a div like crush said and then position it relatively, then apply a id to each such as linkone. Then in jquery or javascript, do a onclick event for the button and just set the linking bar display to block. Make sure you have display none as the default

Comment: I would use a background image for the `td` of just a single black pixel. With `background-position` and `background-repeat` you can make the background appear only on the right or left part of the cell. Use class names accordingly and it should be done...

Comment: @Tallmaris That's a good idea too.

Comment: hah, @user2067005 ... that's pretty much what I just fiddled, so ... +1 for great minds

Comment: @Dom Day +1 for the same reason. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here's a quick fiddle for you. You'll have to style it and tweak positioning and all that, but it should get you started.

http://jsfiddle.net/WtPQE/

css

```
.line-linkage {
    width: 92%;
    height: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
    top: -58px;
    left: 52%;
    z-index: -1000;
}

.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

js

```
$('.line-linkage').addClass('hidden');

$('.ft').on( 'click', function () {
    $(this).parent().next('.line-linkage').toggleClass('hidden');
})
```

Comment: Just a suggestion to sameer. You might want to add some checks in there to prevent the user from "breaking the line"

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it with css only:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kCGt2/

Used Sotiris solution for the middle horizontal line. 
[can I center a border with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831461/can-i-center-a-border-with-css)

Html:

```
<div class="steps">
    1
</div>
<div class="hr">
    <div class="line"></div>
</div>
<div class="steps">
    2
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    float: left;
}

.hr {
    height:15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-top:13px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.steps {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you've already found a solution but for my own practice I came up with one too. This one is pure CSS based with semantic HTML; the click functionality is implemented with JavaScript.

You can easily do it without JavaScript by adding the `completed` HTML class to the appropriate list items.

[See the jsFiddle for this example.](http://jsfiddle.net/8PNzc/1/)

### HTML

```
<ol>
    <li style='background: orange'></li>
    <li style='background: lightblue'></li>
    <li style='background: lime'></li>
    <li style='background: yellow'></li>
</ol>
```

### CSS

Adjust the positioning and borders as necessary.

```
ol {
    counter-reset: steps;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-position: inside;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}
ol > li {
    display: inline-block;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    left: 10%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 0;
    border: 0 solid #000;
    line-height: 2em;
    margin: 1em 0 0.5em 2em;
    counter-increment: steps;
}
ol > li.completed:not(:last-child) {
    border-width: 0.15em 0;
}
ol > li::before {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1em;
    right: 1.5em;
    width: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: inherit;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 0.1em;
    content: counter(steps);
}
ol > li::after {
    position: relative;
    top: 1em;
    right: 50%;
    width: 5em;
    line-height: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0.4em;
    content: 'Step ' counter(steps);
    background-color: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

### JavaScript (jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li').click(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('completed');
        $(this).nextAll().removeClass('completed');
        $(this).prevAll('li').addClass('completed');
    });
});
```

Of course if you need to support IE < 9, you're SOL on this one.

Comment: Thanks rink I will surely look into this. Thanks again!